# While loop in Python stopping before False

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, jupyter

I'm having a list of strings. I don't need some of the strings as it's a repeating header.
I defined a function using while loop that should remove the strings, however I need to run the cell multiple times as the while loop stops before i=len(list_of_strings).
If I run the cell multiple times, then it eventually works.
What did I do wrong?

```
def header_eraser(list_of_strings):
    i=0
    while i < len(list_of_strings):
        if list_of_strings[i] in headers:
            del list_of_strings[i]
            i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
```

Comment: If you're deleting an index, you don't need to increment `i` since the next index will have moved to current position

Comment: You should probably look into list comprehensions, because deleting stuff from a list while iterating can be quite troublesome.

Comment: By the way I would build another list from the previous one to avoid deleting elements while walking the list. Have a look at [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: @Sayse: Ah, of course!!!! Thanks a lot, feeling stupid enough now.

Comment: @MetallimaX, MitchellOlislagers
Thanks a lot, will do.

Comment: Related: [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

As [Sayse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324033/sayse) said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65812655/while-loop-in-python-stopping-before-false#comment116361520_65812655):

> If you're deleting an index, you don't need to increment `i` since the next index will have moved to current position

i.e.

```
def header_eraser(list_of_strings):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_of_strings):
        if list_of_strings[i] in headers:
            del list_of_strings[i]
            # i += 1  # <- Remove this line
        else:
            i += 1
```

However, you might find it easier to use a list comprehension, which requires returning a new list instead of modifying the existing one:

```
def header_eraser(list_of_strings):
    return [s for s in list_of_strings if s not in headers]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you remove an element, the length of the list changes and therefore you are skipping some elements, that's why if you run it multiple times it works.

I would suggest a `for` loop here, so you don't have to worry abount indexes:

```
def header_eraser(list_of_strings):
    new_list = []
    for s in list_of_strings:
        if s not in headers:
            new_list.append(s)
    return new_list
```

This can also be written as a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [s for s in list_of_strings if s not in headers]
```